# I am getting nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

Tags: sql, oracle

this is my query,

```
SELECT
     MAX(CASE WHEN rownumber='1' THEN DISPOSITON END) AS Dispostion
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN rownumber='1' THEN SUB_DISPOSITION END) AS SUB_DISPOSITION
    ,CUST_NAME
    ,MOBILE_NO
    ,EMAIL_ID
    ,LINE_OF_BUSINESS
    ,PRODUCT_CODE
    ,REGISTRATION_NUMBER 
FROM
(
    SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY task_id ORDER BY CREATED_DATE ASC) AS rownumber
        ,a.DISPOSITON
        ,a.SUB_DISPOSITION
        ,b.CUST_NAME
        ,b.MOBILE_NO
        ,b.EMAIL_ID
        ,b.LINE_OF_BUSINESS
        ,b.PRODUCT_CODE
        ,b.REGISTRATION_NUMBER
    FROM CLICK_TO_CALL_AUDIT_LOG a 
    INNER JOIN IM_DATA b
        ON a.task_id=b.task_code
            AND UPPER(a.DISPOSITON) = UPPER(:Dis) 
            AND UPPER(a.SUB_DISPOSITION) in (UPPER(:subDis))
            AND a.CREATED_DATE BETWEEN to_timestamp(:before , 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss') 
            AND to_timestamp(:current, 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss') 
    WHERE b.ALLOCATED_USER IN (:userNameList)
    AND b.IS_LATEST = 'Y'
    AND b.TASK_STATUS <> 'JUNK LEAD'
    AND b.LINE_OF_BUSINESS = :LOB
) R
GROUP BY
     CUST_NAME
    ,MOBILE_NO
    ,EMAIL_ID
    ,LINE_OF_BUSINESS
    ,PRODUCT_CODE
    ,REGISTRATION_NUMBER;
```

Comment: `where b.ALLOCATED_USER in 
            (:userNameList)` you cannot pass filter by list this way. What is the type and content of `:userNameList`?

Comment: userNameList  is a list of String type. and i am getting error, while i convert the all data to uppercase. here  UPPER(a.SUB_DISPOSITION) in (UPPER(:subDis))

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
AND UPPER(a.SUB_DISPOSITION) in (UPPER(:subDis))
```

should most probably be rewritten so that it represents *rows* (instead of a, presumably, comma-separated list of values). Something like this:

```
and upper(a.sub_disposition) in (select trim(regexp_substr(upper(:subDis), '[^,]+', 1, level))
                                 from dual
                                 connect by level <= regexp_count(:subDis, ',') + 1
                                )
```

The same goes for

```
WHERE b.ALLOCATED_USER IN (:userNameList)
```

I presumed that variables (such as `userNameList`) looks like e.g. `'Scott,Tiger,Wood,King'`. If it looks differently, code should also be adjusted.